# prepared transaction is busy error in citus worker nodes

Tags: citus

I am using Citus cluster (11.2 version ), with row based sharding and getting errors related to prepared transactions and data seems to be not getting updated as expected.

ERROR,42704,"prepared transaction with identifier ""citus_0_3700313_364961519_2207"" does not exist",,,,,,"ROLLBACK PREPARED 'citus_0_3700313_364961519_2207'",,,"citus_internal gpid=10000083689","client backend",,-2016593872441745776

ERROR,55000,"prepared transaction with identifier ""citus_0_3545890_364118025_605"" is busy",,,,,,"ROLLBACK PREPARED 'citus_0_3545890_364118025_605'",,,"citus_internal gpid=10000083689","client backend",,-3654212936049697445

max_prepared_transaction is set to 1200 on all nodes. Any help in solving this issue ??